# Why isn't my boolean variable working in if statements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this variable to get the value from a hidden field:

```
var Extend = $('#<%= Extend_.ClientID%>').val();
```

The value of the field is a bool type, true or false. Then I use this variable in these if conditions, but they're not working:

```js
if (Extend === false) {

    alert('test');
}
else if (Extend === true) {

    alert('test2');
}
```

Why don't my if conditions work?

Comment: `.val()` off of most input elements will be a string. `===` is forcing you to compare a string to a boolean.  That will never be true

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Yousaf i don't now why my condition not working

Comment: first comment explained the reason.

Comment: **Extend** will return value is boolean? if yes then you can't compare for that. just simple put that **if(Extend)** . **Extend**  true then go inside otherwise outside **else** condition.

Comment: @JayParmar Why can you not compare boolean? `true === true` works just fine.  That's not the issue with this problem.

Comment: but why you have to do [true === true](). if we have put into simply like this **if(Extend)** because of the if already checked that **true false**

Comment: @JayParmar Because as I explained in my first comment, `val()` does not return a boolean.  It returns a string.  And strict comparison (`===`) negates type coersion during comparisons.  And elements of different types will never be equal without coersion.

Comment: then you will put simply like this **!!Extend** it also working

Comment: @JayParmar No, because !!"true" === true, and !!"false" === true, because a non-empty string is truthy

Comment: The solution is to either convert the value to a boolean, or switch to `==` to allow for coersive equality, or compare the string to a string of "true" or "false".  It's as simple as that

Answer (score 2):

Getting the value from an input field using .val() or .value NEVER returns a boolean. It returns a string instead.

This code will turn the string into a boolean for you:

```
var Extend = ($('#<%= Extend_.ClientID%>').val()=='true');
```

Also, when you're using a boolean variable, it's usually considered better style to just use `else` instead of `else if`, like so:

```js
if (Extend) { // Extend is true
    alert('test');
}
else { // Extend is false
    alert('test2');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After this line:

```js
var Extend = $('#<%= Extend_.ClientID%>').val();
```

The value of `Extend` is actually a string, not a boolean. So your if statements will work it you compare it to the correct string values. Probably something like:

```js
if (Extend === "false") {

    alert('test');
}
else if (Extend === "true") {

    alert('test2');
}
```

If that still doesn't work, double-check which values your hidden field uses when it's true or false. Since it's really a string under the hood, there are a few different conventions I've seen for representing true and false values: `"True"` and "`False`", "`1"` and `"0"`, `"true"` and `""`... Which one your program is using depends on how your hidden field was programmed.

Comment: Getting strings and booleans mixed up has bit me hard in the past. This is the kind of subtle mistake that seems obvious in retrospect but is very difficult to notice the first few times you encounter it, I think everyone has dealt with it at some point!

Comment: Comparing string to a string should always be done with " == " not " ===" because of type conversion .
Also, as he stated, he needs to use Boolean and with your code, if a value isn't "true" or "false" your code wouldn't do anything.

Comment: @Ognjen if you are comparing a string to a string, `==` and `===` behave the same way.

Comment: @Ognjen I disagree, I think using `===` is better. Comparing strings either way will work, and in general `===` avoids a whole lot of subtle and unexpected behaviors with types being silently converted. And it doesn't matter whether `Extend` is a boolean variable if the if statements it's used in works correctly.